# Use of unresolved identifier 'InstanceIDAPNSTokenType'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

The issue of unresolved identifier has been solved before and I did all the steps from repo to install (remove the firebase from pod) and reinstall with the firebase in pod...etc and still it did not fix this problem. This issue along with other were generated once I updated the pod.  The issue occurs in with a function in AppDelegate.

Here is my `AppDelegate.swift`

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseMessaging
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, MessagingDelegate, 
UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    FirebaseApp.configure()

    // Messaging Delegate
    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self

    // Notification delegate
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate

        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })

    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    return true
}

func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {

    print("Registered with FCM with token:", fcmToken)
    [Messaging.messaging().fcmToken!:Messaging.messaging().fcmToken as AnyObject]
}

//
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

    InstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: InstanceIDAPNSTokenType.sandbox)
}

// Listen for user notifications - basically show the notification while a user is on foreground mode
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    completionHandler(.alert)

    // Reset badge number to zero
    if let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {

        let dbRef = Database.database().reference()
        dbRef.child("Users Info").child(userID).updateChildValues(["badge":"0"], withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in
            if err != nil {
                print(err!)
                return
            }
        })

    }


}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {


    if let mainTabBarController = window?.rootViewController as? MainTabBarControllerViewController {

        mainTabBarController.selectedIndex = 1

        mainTabBarController.tabBar.items?[1].badgeValue = nil


    }

}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    completionHandler(.newData)

    if let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? [String:Any] {
        let badgeNumber = aps["badge"] as! Int

        if let mainTabBarController = window?.rootViewController as? MainTabBarControllerViewController {

            mainTabBarController.tabBar.items?[1].badgeValue = String(Int(badgeNumber))

        }

    }

}



func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {


}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {

}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

    if let mainTabBarController = window?.rootViewController as? MainTabBarControllerViewController {

        if  mainTabBarController.selectedIndex == 1 {

            // Reset Requests tab's badge
            mainTabBarController.tabBar.items?[1].badgeValue = nil
        }

    }


    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0

    // Reset badge number to zero
    if let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {

        let dbRef = Database.database().reference()
        dbRef.child("Users Info").child(userID).updateChildValues(["badge":"0"], withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in
            if err != nil {
                print(err!)
                return
            }
        })

    }


}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}


}
```

and here is where the error pops up from the `AppDelegate`

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

    InstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: InstanceIDAPNSTokenType.sandbox)
}
```

Comment: What is this `setAPNSToken` and what are you trying to do with it? I do not see it in the [reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseinstanceid/api/reference/Classes/FIRInstanceID) for Instance ID.

Comment: It is for the remote notification.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you're on Firebase 5.x and use set the APNS token with the Firebase Messaging class instead of InstanceID.

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client

Comment: Thanks Paul!  I guessed the setASPNSToken does not exist anymore.  I replaced with Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken.  I am not ultimately sure if this is the solution or not but works fine.

Answer (score 3):

I removed the following code

```
InstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: InstanceIDAPNSTokenType.sandbox)
```

and replaced it with

```
Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
```

tested and worked fine!